# FOSElastica "Cannot find corresponding Doctrine objects for all Elastica results" - delete the missing one

Tags: elasticsearch, exception, doctrine, resultset, foselasticabundle

I have a big cms project done in symfony+doctrine+foselastica.

Sometimes, if a db persistence is missing I get an exception like "Cannot find corresponding Doctrine objects for all Elastica results" (for example in a lilsting page).

I've added

```
persistence:
                    elastica_to_model_transformer:
                        ignore_missing: true
```

in my .yml config to avoid the error, and it works.

But I think: is there a way to ALSO delete from elastic the missing one? Maybe another config, or something to be added in the doctrine entity.

Thanks!